# is there any easy way to expose methods of private parent class c++

Tags: c++

Is there any way to directly expose some methods of private parent class.
In the following example if I have an object of type Child I want to be able to directly call method a() of its parent, but not b();
Current solution spawns a lot of boilerplate code especially if there are a lot of arguments.

```
class Parent {
    public:
        void a(int p1, double p2, int p3, std::vector <int> &p4);
        void b();
    };
class Child : private Parent {
    public:
        void a(int p1, double p2, int p3, std::vector <int> &p4) {
            Parent::a(p1, p2, p3, p4);
            }
   };
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the using declaration.

```
class Child : private Parent {
    public:
        using Parent::a;
   };
```

Answer (score 3):

This might help: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/private-inheritance.html#faq-24.6

```
class Child : protected Parent
{
  public:
    using Parent::a;
}
```

Edit: added `public`.