# How to avoid the need to specify deleter for std::shared_ptr every time it's constructed or reset?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

`std::unique_ptr` has 2 template parameters, the second of which is the deleter to be used. Thanks to this fact, one can easily alias a `unique_ptr` to a type, which requires a custom deleter (e.g. `SDL_Texture`), in the following manner:

```
using SDL_TexturePtr = unique_ptr<SDL_Texture, SDL2PtrDeleter>;
```

...where `SDL2PtrDeleter` is a functor to be used as deleter.

Given this alias, programmers are able to construct and reset `SDL_TexturePtr` without caring or even knowing about custom deleter:

```
SDL_TexturePtr ptexture(SDL_CreateTexture(/*args*/));

//...

ptexture.reset(SDL_CreateTexture(/*args*/));
```

---

`std::shared_ptr`, on the other hand, doesn't have a template parameter, which would allow specifying the deleter as part of the type, so the following is illegal:

```
// error: wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 1)
using SDL_TextureSharedPtr = shared_ptr<SDL_Texture, SDL2PtrDeleter>;
```

So, the best one can do with a type alias is:

```
using SDL_TextureSharedPtr = shared_ptr<SDL_Texture>;
```

But this has few advantages over using `shared_ptr<SDL_Texture>` explicitly, since the user must know the deleter function to use and specify it each time they construct or reset an `SDL_TextureSharedPtr` anyway:

```
SDL_TextureSharedPtr ptexture(SDL_CreateTexture(/*args*/), SDL_DestroyTexture);

//...

ptexture.reset(SDL_CreateTexture(/*args*/), SDL_DestroyTexture);
```

As you can see from the example above, the user needs to know the correct function to delete `SDL_Texture` (which is `SDL_DestroyTexture()`) and pass a pointer to it every time. Besides being inconvenient, this creates a minor probability that a programmer might introduce a bug by specifying an incorrect function as a deleter.

---

I would like to somehow encapsulate the deleter in the type of shared pointer itself. Since there is no way, as far as I can see, to achieve this just by using a type alias, I have considered 3 options:

1. Create a class, wrapping `std::shared_ptr<T>`, which would duplicate the interface of `shared_ptr` but allow specifying a deleter functor via its own template parameter. This wrapper would then supply a pointer to its deleter instance's `operator()` when invoking constructor or `reset()` method of its underlying `std::shared_ptr<T>` instance from its own constructor or `reset()` method, respectively. The downside, of course, is that the entire, quite sizeable, interface of `std::shared_ptr` would have to be duplicated in this wrapping class, which is WET.
2. Create a subclass of `std::shared_ptr<T>`, which would allow specifying a deleter functor via its own template parameter. This would, assuming `public` inheritance, help us avoid the need to duplicate `shared_ptr`'s interface, but would open a can of worms of its own. Even though `std::shared_ptr` is not `final`, it doesn't seem to have been designed to be subclassed, since it has a non-virtual destructor (though this is not a problem in this particular case). What's worse, `reset()` method in `shared_ptr` is not virtual, and so can't be overridden - only shadowed, which opens the door for incorrect usage: with `public` inheritance, users might pass a reference to an instance of our subclass to some API, accepting `std::shared_ptr<T>&`, whose implementation might invoke `reset()`, circumventing our method entirely. With non-public inheritance we get the same as with option #1.

For both of the above options, in the end, `SDL_TextureSharedPtr` could be expressed as following, assuming `MySharedPtr<T, Deleter>` is our (sub)class:

```
using SDL_TextureSharedPtr = MySharedPtr<SDL_Texture, SDL2PtrDeleter>;
```

3. *The third option used to be here and it involved specializing `std::default_delete<T>`. It was based on my incorrect assumption that `std::shared_ptr<T>` uses `std::default_delete<T>`, like `unique_ptr` does, if no deleter has been provided explicitly. This is **not** the case. Thanks to `@DieterLücking` for pointing this out!*

---

Given these options and the reasoning above, here is my question.

**Have I missed a simpler way to avoid having to specify a deleter for `std::shared_ptr<T>` each time its instance is constructed or `reset()`?**

If not, is my reasoning correct for the options I listed? Are there other objective reasons to prefer one of these options over another?

Comment: Why not wrap the class itself to make it RAII conforming, and adjust `shared_ptr`'s first template argument?

Comment: I don't yet see why you really need a custom deleter. Wouldn't putting `SDL_DestroyTexture(ptr);` to the destructor work as well with the default deleter?

Comment: @lorro: that only works for textures. The goal is to work for any type T.

Comment: A better question is this: why do you have so many places in your code where you are constructing or resetting SDL textures? That should really be localized to a scant few locations.

Comment: @lorro: You assume that `SDL_Texture` is a C++ type with a destructor. The point of having deleters at all is to handle types which have *no destructors*, such as types created by C-based libraries.

Comment: The third option is no option: std::default_delete is not applied to std::shared_ptr, unless it is passed explicitly as deleter to the constructor.

Comment: @DieterLücking Yes, you are right, my mistake. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> using SDL_TexturePtr = unique_ptr<SDL_Texture, SDL2PtrDeleter>;
> ```
>
> Given this alias, programmers are able to construct and reset `SDL_TexturePtr` without caring or even knowing about custom deleter:

Well, that's an (often fatal) over-simplification. It's rather that iff the default-constructed deleter is suitable for construction, respectively the current value of the deleter is suitable for the reset pointer, than it need not be manually changed.

You are right about the disadvantages you found for wrapping or extending `shared_ptr`, though some may say it allows you to add new instance-methods.
You should minimize coupling though, which means prefering free functions, as you don't need more than the existing public interface to write them.

If not specifying a deleter would result in using `std::default_delete` (which it unfortunately doesn't) and you only need one deleter per type, or the standard delete-expression would fit your use-case (which it doesn't seem to), the third option would be best you could choose.

Thus, a different option:
Use a constructor-function to abstract away the (possibly complex) construction and custom deleter.
This way you can only write it once, and liberal use of `auto` can further reduce your headaches.

Comment: The third option is no option: std::default_delete is not applied to std::shared_ptr, unless it is passed explicitly as deleter to the constructor.

Comment: @DieterLücking: Just re-read it, and thanks, you are unfortunately right. Now fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You did not include, as an option, private inheritance with copious `using` directives to expose unchanged functionality.

It is simpler than rewriting shared ptr while usong a private copy, but lets you write a custom `reset` with no danger of exposure.

Also note that shared ptr has a converting ctor from unique ptr.  If your factory functions create unique ptrs, they can be assigned to shared ptrs if needed,mand the correct deleter is used.  Eliminate raw pointers in your code and the problem of reset goes away.

Comment: @nicol it directly answers "Have I missed a simpler way to avoid having to specify a deleter for std::shared_ptr<T> each time its instance is constructed or reset()?"  This is an option he missed that is simpler than an option the OP listed.

Comment: @Yakk Thank you, here's an upvote. To be honest, I had to Google what you mean by "copious `using` directives to expose unchanged functionality", since I have never encountered `using` being used to expose private parent's methods (I guess my encounters with `private` inheritance happened quite rarely in general). This [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2351632/1051764) cleared it up for me. May I ask you to include a brief code sample, illustrating your idea with `using` parent members, or a link to the answer I mentioned, for the benefit of others, who, like me, might be in the dark.

Comment: @terra heh, I said it was an answer not a great one.  ;)  Busy, fathers day weekend.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use a [veneer](http://synesis.com.au/resources/articles/cpp/veneers.pdf):

```
// A shared_ptr which will use SDL2PtrDeleter **by default**:
class SharedTexure : public std::shared_ptr<SDL_Texture> {
public:
  constexpr SharedTexure() : std::shared_ptr<SDL_Texture>() {}
  constexpr SharedTexure(std::nullptr_t) : std::shared_ptr<SDL_Texture>() {}
  explicit SharedTexure(SDL_Texture* texture) :
    std::shared_ptr<SDL_Texture>(texture, SDL2PtrDeleter()) {}
  SharedTexture(std::shared_ptr<SDL_Texture> texture) :
    std::shared_ptr<SDL_Texture>(std::move(texture)) {}
};
```

Which can be generalized with:

```
template<class T, class D>
class shared_ptr : public std::shared_ptr<T> {
public:
  constexpr shared_ptr() : std::shared_ptr<T>() {}
  constexpr shared_ptr(std::nullptr_t) : std::shared_ptr<T>() {}
  template<class U>
  explicit shared_ptr(U* ptr) :
    std::shared_ptr<T>(ptr, D()) {}
  template<class U>
  shared_ptr(std::shared_ptr<U> ptr) :
    std::shared_ptr<T>(std::move(ptr)) {}
};

using SharedTexure = shared_ptr<SDL_Texture, SDL2PtrDeleter>;
```

You should be able to inherit constructors:

```
template<class T, class D>
class shared_ptr : public std::shared_ptr<T> {
public:
  using std::shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr;
  template<class U>
  explicit shared_ptr(U* ptr) :
    std::shared_ptr<T>(ptr, D()) {}
};
```

> it doesn't seem to have been designed to be subclassed,
>   since it has a non-virtual destructor

The [referenced paper](http://synesis.com.au/resources/articles/cpp/veneers.pdf) implies that it is safe for this use case. It'd be interesting to have suitable references from the standard, however.

Comment: Thanks for the link. This is nice, but, if I haven't missed anything, this doesn't seem to address the part concerning `reset()`.

Answer (score 1):

You are too hung up on putting the deleter in the type itself. Focus instead on where `shared_ptr` *instances* come from.

The most effective solution to this problem is to properly centralize where `shared_ptr`s for this system are getting introduced. There should be a single function which generates them; it is responsible for attaching the appropriate deleter.

Obviously such a system offers no guarantees. However, if you simply never use `shared_ptr::reset` (and really, there are few reasons to do so) and you never directly construct one (copying/moving is fine, but other constructors are not), then you're safe. If you need to reassign a `shared_ptr` to a new instance, just use `operator=`; that's what it's for.

Ultimately, this is no different from a codebase that makes liberal use of `make_shared`.

Answer (score 0):

Just move a `unique_ptr` into a `shared_ptr`. The shared_ptr will inherit the custom deleter. See [code](https://godbolt.org/z/dbddqaTbz) (sorry was experimenting with cJSON lib but you'll get the point):

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct cJSON { } obj;

extern "C" cJSON* cJSON_ParseWithLength() { return &obj; }

void cJSON_Delete(cJSON* item)
{
    std::cout << "custom deleter used" << std::endl;
}

auto factory()
{
    return std::unique_ptr<cJSON, decltype(&cJSON_Delete)>{ cJSON_ParseWithLength(), cJSON_Delete };
}

int main()
{
    auto uptr = factory();
    std::shared_ptr sptr{std::move(uptr)};

    sptr.reset();

    std::cout << "now we're done" << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
custom deleter used
now we're done
```